# Ramsey (graph) theory question with tree and girth

Tags: graph-theory, ramsey-theory

Sorry for the abundance of questions I'm asking. Test is soon...

Prove that for every tree $T$ and every $g \in \mathbb{N}$, exist $G$ with girth $g$, so that in any 2-edge-coloring of $G$ there is a monochromatic copy of $T$.

Anyone have an idea how to attack this question?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Edge coloring. Fixed.

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1113312/girth-and-moochromatic-copy-of-trees/1116167#1116167