# Girth and monochromatic copy of trees

Tags: graph-theory, ramsey-theory

**Question:**

Prove that for every tree $T$ and every integer $g$ there exists a graph $G$ without cycles of length up to $g$ and such that every two-coloring of the edges of $G$ contains a monochromatic copy of $T$.

**Thoughts**:
I saw something similar here https://www.dpmms.cam.ac.uk/~dc340/RamseyLecture5.pdf,
but besides the $\mathrm{girth}(G)=g$, I couldn't find a way to connect the information into a start for a proof. Any Hints? 
(This is similar to this [Ramsey (graph) theory question with tree and girth](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/186378/ramsey-graph-theory-question-with-tree-and-girth) which has no answer)

**added after trying to solve using hints in comment:**

I have this idea for a proof - Want to verify I got this right as it still seems difficult. I'll use facts 1-4 from here http://how360.org/mathematics/675109/monochromatic-tree .

- From fact 2 we have that exists a graph $G_{g,k}: \delta(G_{g,k})\ge k=|V(T)|$.
- From fact 3 we have that $G_{g,k}$ has a sub-graph H s.t $\delta (H)\ge\frac {|E(G)|}{|V(G)|}\ge k (***)$.
- From fact 1 we have that $H$ contains a copy of T.
- From fact 4 (pigeonhole) we have that $\frac {|E(G)|}{|V(G)|} \ge \frac {|E(H)|}{|V(G)|} \ge \frac{|E(G)|}{2|V(G)|}$ or $\frac {|E(G)|}{|V(G)|} \ge \frac {|E(G\setminus H)|}{|V(G)|} \ge \frac{|E(G)|}{2|V(G)|}$
- A 2-coloring may be viewed as a partition of G to H (Blue) and H-complement (Red) therefore H or H-complement contains a copy of T - so we have G which has the required girth and it contains a monochromatic copy of T.

The only problem I have now is how to justify the (***) move.

Comment: Isn't your question just a duplicate of that old unanswered question? What's the difference?

Comment: http://how360.org/mathematics/675109/monochromatic-tree

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Filling in the gap (this was asked in the problem (***) and proves item 4 below):

We will write $n(G)$ for $|V(G)|$ and $e(G)$ for $|E(G)|$ and $a(G)$ for $\frac{e(G)}{n(G)}$.

If $G$ does not contain a vertex $v$ with $d(v)<a(G)$, then $\delta(G)\geq a(G)$ and we are done.

Otherwise we produce a graph $G_2$ by removing a vertex $v$ with $d(v)<a(G)$.
We get $a(G_2)=\frac{e(G_2)}{n(G_2)}\geq\frac{e(G)-a(G)}{n(G)-1}=a(G)$.

You can repeat this procedure until you arrive at a subgraph $H$ that has $\delta(H)\geq a(H)\geq a(G)$.

ADDED:

I am not sure if your breakdown of the problem is correct, at least I see several problems in it. Here is a breakdown that seems to work.

1. Find a graph $G$ with girth at least $g$ and minimum degree at least $4k$, where $k=|V(T)|$.
2. This graph has $\frac{|E(G)|}{|V(G)|}\geq 2k$.
3. Make an edge-2-coloring. This produces an edge partition $E_1,E_2$ and by symmetry and the pigeonhole principle we may assume that $\frac{|E_1|}{|V(G)|}\geq k$.
4. In the spanning subgraph of $G$ with edges $E_1$ you can find a subgraph $H$ with $\delta(H)\geq k$.
5. This subgraph must contain $T$.

ADDED PROOF OF ITEM 1: (For integers $g$ and $k$ there is a graph $G$ with girth at least $g$ and minimum degree at least $k$.)

Let $f(t)=1+k(\sum_{i=0}^t(k-1)^i)$ and take $n>f(2g-1)+kf(g-1)f(2g-1)$.

Construct a graph as follows:
start with an empty graph on $n$ vertices, then arbitrarily choose 2 vertices of degree less than $k$
and distance more than $g$ and connect them. Keep doing this until you cannot proceed.

At this moment you have a graph with $n$ vertices, maximum degree $k$ and girth at least $g$.

Now find a vertex $v$ of degree less than $k$ (if there is none, we are done).
Note that all vertices of degree less than $k$ must have distance at most $g$ from $v$
(or we would not have stopped our first process), so there are at most $f(g-1)$ vertices of degree less than $k$.

In the same way there are at most $f(2g-1)$ vertices at distance at most $2g$ from $v$.
This means that there are at least $kf(g-1)f(2g-1)$ vertices that are further than $g$ away from any
low-degree vertex.

We finish the process by iteratively adding edges from a low degree vertex to a far away vertex.
Since we need to add at most $kf(g-1)$ edges and since each addition removes at most $f(2g-1)$
far away vertices we have enough far away vertices to make all vertices of degree at least $k$.

Comment: Could you please explain why the one before last line is correct? (The inequality)

Comment: I mean- isn't $e(G_2)\le e(G)-a(G)$ since $G_2$ has less edges?

Comment: Since $d(v)<a(G)$, we remove less than $a(G)$ edges when we remove $v$, so $e(G_2)\geq e(G)-a(G)$. Indeed $G_2$ has less edges, so $e(G_2)<e(G)$, but we are not interested in that part.

Comment: How does this allow us to solve the problem? Though I've understood all these facts, I don't see how to put them together. Why must every coloring form an $H$ with this property (we only know about the existence of $H$)? And what is the significance of $a(G)=e(G)/n(G)$ and how do we know it's more than $k$?

Comment: @ctlaltdefeat: I do not believe the breakdown the OP did in the question is correct. I have added an alternative to the answer. Do you understand that one?

Comment: Could you please provide a link for the proof of fact 2, I've been having difficulties proving that too, I've found in one of my books a proof for a similar claim but with chromatic color (not min-degree). Is this the same idea?

Comment: Yeah, I think so, thanks. Interesting how you didn't use any Ramsey considerations (though the problem seems like one) and most of the "work" seems to be in fact 1 (Erdos' result that "large" graphs with high girth exist).

Comment: @user1685224: I have no link, but found a proof in my own collection and I don't remember the source.

Comment: Man, really great thanks. Graph theory is soooo tough!

Comment: Is there a reason $f(t)$'s definition is as specific as it is? Couldn't you just take $f(t)=1+tk^{t+1}$?

Comment: @crlaltdefeat: $f(t)$ is the maximum number of vertices in a ball of radius $t+1$ when the maximum degree is $k$. It is used in many proofs in graph theory.